# Undo .removeAtribute function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm looking for a solution to restore a removed attribute. I'm not an experienced programmer, so I'm not sure where to start when sharing my code, so I'll try to give some context below.

I have an image of a map that has several hidden overlays. These overlays are activated by a series of adjacent buttons.

Each of these buttons has a `mouseover` and `mouseout` event, which temporarily reveals the overlay. They also have an `onclick` event that permanently displays the overlay. I've used a `.removeAtribute` function to remove the `mouseout` event so that my overlay is permanent.

All other layers are still visible with the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events (so that you can make comparisons).

When I `onclick` another overlay button, it clears the previous one, however, now the `mouseout` event for the previously selected button is still inactive, so hovering over it causes the overlay to appear permanently.

How can I restore the `mouseout` event after I've removed it?

I have tried to use `.setAttribute("onmouseout")`, but I've had no luck in making that work.

Hopefully, this all makes some sense; I'll post some of my code below, which might help give further context.

```js
function btn01On() {
   document.getElementById("btn01").removeAttribute("onmouseout");
}

function btnClear() {
   document.getElementById("btn01").setAttribute("onmouseout");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn01" class="map-button map-button1"
onclick="MM_showHideLayers('InfoCurrentExc','','show','OverlayCurrentExc','','show');btn01On();" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('OverlayCurrentExc','','show')" onmouseout="MM_showHideLayers('OverlayCurrentExc','','show')">
Current Excavation
</button>
```

Comment: Usually setting up event handlers using `onevent` attribute is not the recommended way, See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#dom_event_handler_list

Comment: [`setAttribute(name, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) would need a value. It's kind of an `a=123` thing, attempting to write it as `a=` and hoping the computer will find out the `123` itself can't really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was lucky enough to find someone who had a fix for this problem. I'll share the code below for anyone who might land here with a similar request.

I don't fully understand how this code works so if someone has a good explanation feel free to share it.

```js
// Remove mouse outs
function btn01On() {
  document.getElementById("btn01").removeAttribute("onmouseout");
}

// keep mouse outs
const buttonIds = ["btn01"];
const mouseOuts = {};
buttonIds.forEach((id) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el) {
    mouseOuts[id] = el.getAttribute('onmouseout');
  }
});

const restoreMouseOutEvent = () => {
  buttonIds.forEach((id) => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el && mouseOuts[id]) {
      el.setAttribute('onmouseout', mouseOuts[id]);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually setting up event handlers using onevent attribute, (although oldest method for event handling) is not the recommended way, See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#dom_event_handler_list.

I recommend using `EventTarget.addEventListener` and `EventTarget.removeEventListener` for your case. Try the code below

```
const mouseoutHandler = function() {
    MM_showHideLayers('OverlayCurrentExc', '', 'show');
};

const mouseOverHandler = function() {
    MM_showHideLayers('OverlayCurrentExc', '', 'show');
};

const button01 = document.getElementById("btn01");
button01.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandler);

function btn01On() {
    if (!mouseoutListener)
        button01.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler);
}

function btnClear() {
    if (mouseoutListener) {
        button01.removeEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutListener);
        mouseoutListener = null;
    }
}


const clickHandler = function() {
    MM_showHideLayers('InfoCurrentExc', '', 'show', 'OverlayCurrentExc', '', 'show');
    btn01On();
}

button01.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you Utkarsh, this has helped with the onmouseout event, however now my onclick event is no longer permanent, I think because the onmouseout is clearing it.

How can I keep the 'OverlayCurrentExc' visible onclick and only clear when I hit the bntClear button?

Comment: @DanielTaylor I didn't get what you mean, and I don't have any familiarity with this function you are using `MM_showHideLayers`. I can help out more if you can tell me what each line does

Comment: @DanielTaylor For now I have updated the answer to move all the inline event logic in your code (onclick, onmouseover) to use addEventLister for event handlers.

Comment: Another question is, is mouseover event also supposed to stop working on clearButton ?